# O que é um Object[ ] no Java?

Tags: java

**Object[ ]**

A alguns dias atrás eu estive programando no Java, e eu procurei uma forma de adicionar algumas opções diferentes ao JOptionPane.showOptionDialog( ), e eu vi em uma resolução que usaram um esse Object:

```
Object[] optionsDialog = {"Primeira","Segunda","Terceira"};
```

Dai eu queria saber

1. O que é esse Object[ ]?
2. Qual a função dele?
3. Ele tem alguma diferença para o array do Java? (achei ele bem semelhante a um array)

Comment: É um array de `Object`. Assim como `int[]` é um array de `int`'s e `String[]` é um array de `String`'s, `Object[]` é um array no qual todos os elementos são `Object` (ou seja, eles podem ser qualquer objeto, por isso funcionou colocar strings nele)

Comment: Então se eu instanciar uma classe em objetos, eu posso coloca-los nesse array?

Comment: No caso do `JOptionPane`, provavelmente optaram por usar `Object[]` porque podem ser passados diferentes tipos de objetos nele. Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)): "*if the objects are components, they are rendered properly; non-String objects are rendered using their toString methods, etc...*" - seria uma forma de dizer que aceita "qualquer coisa"

Comment: Claro que não é exatamente "qualquer coisa", internamente ele deve verificar o tipo e tomar uma ação diferente em cada caso, ou até dar erro caso seja um tipo não-suportado, etc. Enfim, o que pode ou não fazer varia caso a caso

Comment: Entendo, interessante. Muito obrigado

Comment: Complementando e traduzindo o que o @hkotsubo disse, tudo que for possível usar/"suportar" `.toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todas as classes do java são subclasses de Object, e você pode pensar, mas eu não utilzei herança, como assim? o Java faz suas classes herdarem de Object, um toString(), equals() ou hashCode() estamos o trazendo de Object,  Podemos dizer que Object é a principal classe do java.

quando se utiliza  `Object a = valor` esse valor poderá ser qualquer tipo, o contrário não é verdadeiro, não podemos fazer `String a = new Object();` por qual motivo? String é subclasse de Object e não Object subclasse de String.

Um exemplo costumeiro é sobrescrevermos o equals() e hashCode() para compararmos igualdade de objetos, e o toString() para termos dados mais coesos e próximos do que estamos 'na mão'

Então eu poderia utilizar o String ao invéz de Object? sim.

```
String[] optionsDialog = {"Primeira","Segunda","Terceira"};
```

Então eu poderia utilizar Integer ao invéz de Object? sim.

```
Integer[] optionsDialog = {1, 2, 3};
```

há problema em utilizar o object? eu não vejo problema, mas é sempre bom trabalharmos com Objetos de mais alto nível.